# Code chef solution Dynamic programming

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, breadth-first-search

This is the code-chef june challenge question (contest has ended)

Chef loves games! But he likes to invent his own. Now he plays game "Digit Jump". Chef has sequence of digits S1, S2,..., SN,. He is staying in the first digit (S1) and wants to reach the last digit (SN) in the minimal number of jumps.
While staying in some digit x with index i (digit Si) Chef can jump into digits with indices i - 1 (Si-1) and i + 1 (Si+1) but he can't jump out of sequence. Or he can jump into any digit with the same value x.
Help Chef to find the minimal number of jumps he need to reach digit SN from digit S1.

Input

Input contains a single line consist of string S of length N- the sequence of digits.

Output

In a single line print single integer - the minimal number of jumps he needs.

Constraints

1 ≤ N ≤ 10^5
Each symbol of S is a digit from 0 to 9.

Example

Input:
01234567890

Output:
1

Input:
012134444444443

Output:
4

And This is one of the solutions he has provided

Let dp[i] denote the number of steps required to go from position 0 to position i. 
From the previous observations, we know that we wont need more than 20 steps. 
So lets make 20 iterations.

Before starting all the iterations, we will set dp[1] = 0 and dp[i] = infinity for all other i > 1. 
On each iteration, we will calculate Q[k] where Q[k] is the minimum value of dp[i] such that s[i] = k. ie. Q[k] denotes the minimum value of dp over the positions where the digit is equal to k.

We can update the dp by following method. 
dp[i] = min(dp[i], dp[i - 1] + 1, dp[i + 1] + 1, Q[s[i]] + 1);

Here the term dp[i - 1] + 1 denotes that we have come from previous position ie (i - 1). 
Here the term dp[i + 1] + 1 denotes that we have come from next position ie (i + 1). 
The term Q[s[i]] + 1 denotes the minimum number of operations needed to come from a position with same digit as the current i th digit.

You can check the question and editorial here

http://discuss.codechef.com/questions/44800/digjump-editorial?sort=votes&page=2

I did not understand why did he think 20 iterations would suffice.I understood that we would need at most 20 jumps to reach any digit,but how is that related to number of iterations.In fact,there are some users who commented that they iterated only thrice(fwd,backwd and again fwd) and some users who have iterated 10 times and got their solution accepted. And in the bfs solution ,how exactly does the graph looks.can anyone explain with a small example.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved that with simple BFS with one modification. Once you reached digit `D` with distance `d` for the first time you update distance to other positions with digit `D` to `d+1`.

Comment: Can u please explain the bfs solution wuth a small example.I am not even understanding how the graph will look like.

Comment: The graph is linear chain: 0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9